# using class function inside ReturnType<>

Tags: typescript

(this is inside a class) this came up when i hovered over the underline word:

```
(method) default.generateDatabaseSystemBannerObject(): {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    image: string;
    color: `#${string}`;
    type: "CHARACTER" | "WEAPON";
    category: "STANDARD" | "LIMITED" | "EVENT";
    currency: CurrencyTypes;
    ... 5 more ...;
    expiryTimestamp: number;
}
---------------------------------------
Property or signature expected.ts(1131)
---------------------------------------
Duplicate identifier 
'generateDatabaseSystemBannerObject'.
---------------------------------------
ts(2300) Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'generateDatabaseSystemBannerObject' must be of type '() => { id: string; name: string; description: string; image: string; color: `#${string}`; type: "CHARACTER" | "WEAPON"; category: "STANDARD" | "LIMITED" | "EVENT"; currency: CurrencyTypes; ... 5 more ...; expiryTimestamp: number; }', but here has type 'any'.ts(2717)
Banner.ts(244, 5): 'generateDatabaseSystemBannerObject' was also declared here.
```

does this mean i can't do `this.generateDatabaseSystemBannerObject` in the return type?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the function's prototype to the ReturnType utility. You could do that like this:

```
class SomeClass
{
    someMethod(): string[]
    {
        return [];
    }

    anotherMethod()
    {
        const someVar: ReturnType<SomeClass['someMethod']> = ['value'];
    }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgMoHsC2BTAwlWwDew5C5pU0BZNAFwAskATACgEoAuYygJwEsA7AcwDaAXQJF8RCXA5UArhx5xhAblGEAviAmQeSGmg4Ua9ZqrjjJhUEh7RKxUgDVIHNgCVZ8gCoBPAA5oAHmR0LBhoAQByEnRDWjoIoQA+OABeRQiAN0hwGTQElQkNDSA)